# How do you set the gutter color of a mat-grid-list?

Tags: angular-material

How do I set the color between this grids to be a specific color? [gutterColor]="'grey'" is not an option.

```
<div class="detail-container">
    <mat-grid-list cols="6" rowHeight="400px" [gutterSize]="'10px'">
        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]=2
            [rowspan]=2
            [style.background]="'lightblue'">
            One
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]=4
            [rowspan]=1
            [style.background]="'red'">
            Two
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can to set mat-grid-list{background-color: aquamarine;} by CSS